# Solo detecta una columna al cargar csv

Tags: python, pandas, data

Tengo mi serie histórica bajada en un archivo csv, la cual tiene 5 columnas

> ['Date','Price','Open','High",'Low']

Hago lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Lazardi/Desktop/GFG.BA.csv", header=0,index_col=False)

print(df)
```

> ```
>                      Date;Price;Open;High;Low
> 0     01/06/2018;106.400;107.100;107.900;104.500
> 1     31/05/2018;105.800;106.000;107.000;103.500
> 2     30/05/2018;104.000;103.300;107.000;103.300
> 3     29/05/2018;102.700;103.650;106.450;100.050
> 4     28/05/2018;104.000;107.700;108.500;103.000
> 5     27/05/2018;107.600;107.60...0;111.750;106.700
> 6     26/05/2018;108.400;109.900;110.700;108.100
> 7     25/05/2018;111.800;115.000;115.000;110.300
> 8     24/05/2018;115.000;115.000;115.500;114.000
> 9     23/05/2018;114.000;117.000;117.000;114.000
> 10    22/05/2018;115.400;113.950;116.950;112.350
> .................................................
> 4303          20/08/2006;1.532;1.542;1.551;1.523
> 4304          19/08/2006;1.523;1.542;1.542;1.523
> 4305          18/08/2006;1.597;1.606;1.615;1.587
> 4306          17/08/2006;1.606;1.615;1.615;1.597
> 4307          16/08/2006;1.615;1.615;1.615;1.578
> 4308          15/08/2006;1.615;1.642;1.652;1.615
>
> [4309 rows x 1 columns]
>
> df.info() 
>
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 4309 entries, 0 to 4308
> Data columns (total 1 columns):
> Date;Price;Open;High;Low    4309 non-null object
> dtypes: object(1)
> memory usage: 33.7+ KB
> ```

Pregunto, ¿Porqué dice "Data columns (total 1 columns)"?

Veo nuevamente las columnas

> ```
> >>> df.columns
>
> Index(['Date;Price;Open;High;Low'], dtype='object')
> ```

y cuando intento ver las columnas por individual:

```
>>> df[2:10]
```

me las muestra todas como si fueran una sola.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el carácter separador por defecto para las columnas que usa [**`pandas.read_csv`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) es la coma (`,`) no el punto y coma (`;`). Por eso **toma toda la fila como una sola columna**.

Solo tienes que usar el parámetro **`sep`** para indicar el separador correcto. Por otro lado, si quieres parsear la columna `Date` como fechas debes indicarlo con **`parse_dates`** y dado que la fecha tiene formato *dd/mm/yyyy* debes usar además **`dayfirst=True`**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# Esto es solo para emular un fichero csv
csv = StringIO('''
Date;Price;Open;High;Low
01/06/2018;106.400;107.100;107.900;104.500
31/05/2018;105.800;106.000;107.000;103.500
30/05/2018;104.000;103.300;107.000;103.300
29/05/2018;102.700;103.650;106.450;100.050
28/05/2018;104.000;107.700;108.500;103.000
27/05/2018;107.600;107.600;111.750;106.700
26/05/2018;108.400;109.900;110.700;108.100
25/05/2018;111.800;115.000;115.000;110.300
24/05/2018;115.000;115.000;115.500;114.000
23/05/2018;114.000;117.000;117.000;114.000
22/05/2018;115.400;113.950;116.950;112.350
''')


df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", parse_dates=["Date"], dayfirst=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>          Date  Price    Open    High     Low
> 0  2018-06-01  106.4  107.10  107.90  104.50
> 1  2018-05-31  105.8  106.00  107.00  103.50
> 2  2018-05-30  104.0  103.30  107.00  103.30
> 3  2018-05-29  102.7  103.65  106.45  100.05
> 4  2018-05-28  104.0  107.70  108.50  103.00
> 5  2018-05-27  107.6  107.60  111.75  106.70
> 6  2018-05-26  108.4  109.90  110.70  108.10
> 7  2018-05-25  111.8  115.00  115.00  110.30
> 8  2018-05-24  115.0  115.00  115.50  114.00
> 9  2018-05-23  114.0  117.00  117.00  114.00
> 10 2018-05-22  115.4  113.95  116.95  112.35
>
> >>> df.Date
> 0    2018-06-01
> 1    2018-05-31
> 2    2018-05-30
> 3    2018-05-29
> 4    2018-05-28
> 5    2018-05-27
> 6    2018-05-26
> 7    2018-05-25
> 8    2018-05-24
> 9    2018-05-23
> 10   2018-05-22
> Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
> ```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias !